# PHP can't access file on network on one server but can on another

Tags: php, python, windows, networking

I wrote a program in php/html and javascript. Part of it reads a simple text file on a network and parses the data. The program worked as intended on my test machine (apache 2.2 windows 7). However, when I transferred the program to the production server (windows server 2008) it just doesn't work. I know people are going to say well, did you escaped the slashes properly? Did you mapped the drive? etce\ etc. Yes, yes I did. The funny part is that this problem is exclusive to php. I wrote a python script that reads the same exact file on the same exact location and it has no problem on either machine. I then wrote another test script which runs most of the program in php but, leaves the reading of the file on the network in python. That doesn't work either. If I run the same python script through the command prompt it can access the file no problem but, if php calls that same script through the shell_exec() command then it doesn't work on the windows server 2008 machine. And yes, I mapped the address and yes, I can access the file through the other system with the same code no problem. Soooo, suspicion here is that there must be some PHP setup or maybe server setup that does not allows php to access network drives or network files on this one computer. the question then is what can it be? these systems where not setup by me and I have no idea what could control this type of thing. My network admin has no clue either because everything indicates that it should just work. One thing that might be worth mentioning is that the win server 2008 run as a virtual machine or so I have been told. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 
$theFile="\\\\192.168.0.16\\geo\\junk.txt"; #network file does not works
#$theFile="junk.txt"; #local file works fine
$handle = fopen($theFile, "r");
if($handle){
    while (!feof($handle)){
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        echo $buffer."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What user does your IIS server run as?

Comment: Wall of text + no code = frowny face :(

Comment: mschuett How do I find put the user? wavemode3 I will provide the code tomorrow when i get to work but, it is very simple. It pretty much just an open file read line kind of thing. The reason for not providing code is because I don't think that is the problem at all since it works fine on another system and in the case of the python part, it work fine through he command line.

Comment: Added a sample code. Again it works on one machine but not in another. I also tried mapping the drives (not shown in the code). It has to be a configuration thing but, i don't know where to look.

Comment: When I type var_dump(shell_exec('whoami') it syas it is NULL. If I look at the task manager it says the NETWORK SERVICE